# jQuery place p content into attribute

Tags: jquery, attr

this is my first time here...

I have the following scenario:

```
<div class="album-wrap">
    <img src="picture.jpg" alt="Mickey">
    <p class="caption">little mouse</p>
</div>

<div class="album-wrap">
    <img src="picture2.jpg" alt="Donald">
    <p class="caption">little duck</p>
</div>
```

Question is: how could I place the contents of class caption into alt attributes? 
Or maybe create another attribute and place the contents of caption class.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through each container, and get the contents of the `p` element using `.text()`. Then, assign this value to the `alt` attribute using `.attr()`.

```
$(".album-wrap").each(function(){
    var caption = $("p.caption", this).text();
    $("img", this).attr("alt", caption);
})
```

Comment: Man that was fast, I'm impressed! Thanks, this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the alt contents with the text of the caption.

```
$('.caption').each( function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $img = $(this).prev('img');
    $img.attr('alt', $this.text() );
});
```

Append the text of the caption to the alt contents.

```
$('.caption').each( function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $img = $(this).prev('img'),
        alt = $img.attr('alt');
    $img.attr('alt', alt + ': ' + $this.text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the `img` elements and set the `alt` attributes to the inner text of their respective, sibling `p.caption` elements.

```
$('.album-wrap img').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    $img.attr('alt', $img.siblings('.caption').text());
});
```